# Proving differentiability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I just had a question on proving differentiability by showing that the difference quotient exists. I understand in the case of a function like $f(x)=x^2$, where you end up with $((x+h)^2 - x^2)/h = 2x + h = 2x$ as h goes to infinity, but in the case of a function such as $1/x^n$, how do you address the "n" portion since you cannot expand and divide out the $h$ in the denominator?

Comment: what kind of number is $n$?

Answer (score 3):

**METHOD 1:**  BRUTE FORCE USE OF THE DEFINITION OF THE DERIVATIVE

We can actually approach this with brute force using the binomial expansion.  We can write

$$(x+h)^n=x^n\left(1+n\frac hx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{h^n}{x^n}\right)$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(x+h)^n}-\frac{1}{x^n}&=\frac{1}{x^n}\left(\frac{1-\left(1+n\frac hx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{h^n}{x^n}\right)}{\left(1+n\frac hx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{h^n}{x^n}\right)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{x^n}\left(\frac{-\left(n\frac hx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{h^n}{x^n}\right)}{\left(1+n\frac hx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{h^n}{x^n}\right)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{-\left(n\frac h{x^{n+1}}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{x^{n+2}}+\cdots+\frac{h^n}{x^{2n}}\right)}{\left(1+n\frac hx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\frac{h^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{h^n}{x^n}\right)}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Dividing $(1)$ by $h$ and letting $h\to 0$, we obtain the result $-\frac{n}{x^{n+1}}$ as expected.

---

**METHOD 2:**  USE OF THEOREMS

Theorem 1:  The product rule.  $(fg)'=fg'+f'g$.

Theorem 2:  The quotient rule.  $(f/g)'=-fg'/g^2+f'/g$.

Theorem 3:  The derivative of $x$ is $1$.

We use induction to show that $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$ using Theorem $2$ and Theorem $3$.

First observe that Theorem $3$ forms a base case.

Then, we postulate that for some $k$, $(x^k)'=kx^{k-1}$ and examine $(x^{k+1})'$.

Note that $(x^{k+1})'=(x\times x^{k})'$.  By Theorem 2, the product rule, we have $(x\times x^{k})'=x(x^k)'+x^k(x)'=x(kx^{k-1})+x^k=(k+1)x^k$.

Therefore, by induction we have proven that $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$.

Next, we analyze $(1/x^n)'$.  Using Theorem 1 with $f=1$ and $g=x^n$ yields, $(1/x^n)'=-nx^{n-1}/x^{2n}+0=-n/x^{n+1}$ and  we are done!

Comment: I thought about using the binomial expansion, but thought there may be something more simple that I was completely overlooking

Comment: @alecm You were absolutely on the right track!  Well done.

Comment: @alecm Of course, use of the quotient rule along with knowledge of $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$, for $n\ge 0$, is more efficient.  And the latter can be shown using induction and the product rule.

Comment: I thought about those as well, which make it easier, but in this case I needed to do it strictly using the definition of the diff quotient, but like I said wasn't sure once I got the (x+h)^n in the denominator

Comment: @alecm You are doing well then.  And your thinking is sound.

Comment: I added a section on use of theorems, which circumvent the need to invoke the binomial expansion.

Answer (score 1):

We can still manipulate the definition purely algebraically: Let $x \neq 0$; let $n \geq 1$; note that
$$
h^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{(x+h)^{n}} - \frac{1}{x^{n}} \right) = h^{-1}\left( \frac{x^{n} - (x+h)^{n}}{(x^{2}+hx)^{n}} \right) = \frac{-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{k}(x+h)^{n-1-k}}{(x^{2}+hx)^{n}} \to -nx^{-n-1} 
$$
as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help...how did you make the jump from the second to third step, where you included the summation?

Comment: binomial theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting in the form $$x^{\alpha}=e^{\alpha\ln(x)}$$ and the derivative is $$e^{\alpha\ln(x)}\frac{\alpha}{x}=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$$

Comment: That does not address the issue that the OP raised, which was to use the definition of the derivative, not theorems.

Comment: but is follows from the theorems

Comment: Yes, of course it does.  But the OP seems more concerned with using the definition of the derivative directly.  While this approach might be a bit cumbersome, it is straightforward and actually quite tractable.

Comment: yes of course but which definition do you mean?

Comment: The limit definition.  What other definition is there?

Comment: there are many other definitions, but you want to give me a $-1$ please do it

Comment: What is another definition of the derivative?

Comment: "there are many other definitions" Many definitions of the derivative? No.